# MySQL-python installation - wrong architecture - MacOS

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, python-2.7

yesterday I've installed new version of python 2.7.5 via installer on MacOS
and unfortunately MySQL broke down. I got following error when starting
development server:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Volumes/Home/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Volumes/Home/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

**OS**:
Mac OS 10.7.3

**Uname -a**
Darwin Rafals-MacBook-Pro.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

**Python**
2.7.5

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to update your MySQLdb module.

If you have setuptools installed you should be able to do with with the command:

```
easy_install MySQL-python
```

If you don't have setup tools you can install it first:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#unix-based-systems-including-mac-os-x